# Cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type '(NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)'

Tags: ios, swift3

I have created a helper function to load `NSManagedObject`s using Swift 3, which supports iOS 9.0+.

```
class func loadContext(entityName: String, fetchConfiguration: ((NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>) -> Void)?) -> AnyObject? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    // Fetch requested data
    let dataFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)

    // Configure the fetch request with user parameters
    if fetchConfiguration != nil {
        fetchConfiguration!(dataFetchRequest)
    }

    do {
        return try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(dataFetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch feed data, critical error: \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

However I get the following error:

`Cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type '(NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)'`

I have also tried several variants, such as having `let dataFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFechRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)` and they all run into the same error.

Comment: I have come across the exact same issue.  Did you ever find a resolution?  Are generic calls not allowed in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes were a lot simpler, it seems as though xcode wrongfully inferences the "AnyObject" type when converting code from swift-2 to 3.0.

For reference this is the fixed function from @dmorrow's solution.

```
class func loadContext(entityName: String, fetchConfiguration: ((NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>) -> Void)?) -> [NSManagedObject]? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    // Fetch requested data
    let dataFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)

    // Configure the fetch request with user parameters
    fetchConfiguration?(dataFetchRequest)

    do {
        return try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(dataFetchRequest)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch feed data, critical error: \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered on my question [Swift 3/XCode 8 NSManagedObjectContext.fetch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779846/swift-3-xcode-8-nsmanagedobjectcontext-fetch-error).

The error message XCode is providing is incorrect.  The correct fix is to cast your return and your method correctly.

`managedObjectContext.fetch()` returns `[Any]`.  There are three changes you need to make.

1. `class func loadContext(entityName: String, fetchConfiguration: ((NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>) -> Void)?) -> [NSManagedObject]? {`
2. `let dataFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)`
3. `return try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(dataFetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]`

I've submitted a bug report to Apple - https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5049582866137088